# Can I use Improved Trip with Strikes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Can I try to trip with the Maneuvers (Strikes) of a Crusader?

Comment: [Closely related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65604/8610) In fact, I'd call it a duplicate were it not for the presence of *Improved* in the title. Could the body of the question make it clearer that this isn't a duplicate?